# How to set a text padding in a TextField?

Tags: java, libgdx, padding, textfield

[image]

I need to set a left-padding of the text inside a TextField. 
There is a method `setAlign(Align.TOP | BOTTOM | CENTER)` but I need to hardcode a value so it looks nice.

Here's my current code:

```
  TextField loginField = new TextField("", skin);
  TextField passwordField = new TextField("", skin);

  loginField.setMessageText("LOGIN");
  passwordField.setMessageText("PASSWORD");
```

I've tried editing the TextFieldStyle, but still with no success.
Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: You can add a css class with the needed padding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `passwordField.getStyle().background.setLeftWidth` method to add left padding.